# IBM Watson WebSocket connection failure: "HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available"

Tags: websocket, token, ibm-watson

I'm doing the tutorial for IBM Watson Speech-to-text. In the section "[Using the WebSocket interface](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/websockets.html)", subsection "Opening a connection and passing credentials", I copied the following code:

```
var token = watsonToken;
console.log(token); // token looks good
var wsURI = 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?watson-token=' +
  token + '&model=es-ES_BroadbandModel';
var websocket = new WebSocket(wsURI);
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
```

I'm using Angular so I made a value for the token:

```
app.value('watsonToken', 'Ln%2FV...');
```

I get back an error message:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?watson-toke...&model=es-ES_BroadbandModel' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available
```

I tried hardcoding the token:

```
var wsURI = 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?watson-token=Ln%2FV2...&model=es-ES_BroadbandModel';
```

Same error message.

IBM's documentation on [tokens](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/common/getting-started-tokens.html) says that an expired or invalid token will return a 401 error, which I didn't get, so I presume that my token is neither expired nor invalid. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elementary, my dear Watson! There are three or four things to pay attention to with IBM Watson tokens.

First, you won't get a token if you use your IBMid and password. You have to use the username and password that were provided for a project. That username is a string of letters and numbers with hyphens.

Second, the [documentation for tokens](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/common/getting-started-tokens.html) gives you code for getting a token:

```
curl -X GET --user {username}:{password}
--output token
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api"
```

Part of that code is hidden on the webpage, specifically the part that says `/text-to-speech/`. You need to change that to the Watson product or service you want to use, e.g., `/speech-to-text/`. Tokens are for specific projects and specific services.

Third, tokens expire in one hour.

Lastly, I had to put in backslashes to get the code to run in my terminal:

```
curl -X GET --user s0921i-s002d-dh9328d9-hd923:wy928ye98e \
--output token \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can see the Official Example from IBM Developers [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/speech-to-text/recognize_stream.js#L41).

The error is because the authentication does not work fine before you send the request to recognize, try to follow the same step inside this repository, like:

```
const QUERY_PARAMS_ALLOWED = ['model', 'X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out', 'watson-token', 'customization_id'];

/**
 * pipe()-able Node.js Readable/Writeable stream - accepts binary audio and emits text in it's `data` events.
 * Also emits `results` events with interim results and other data.
 * Uses WebSockets under the hood. For audio with no recognizable speech, no `data` events are emitted.
 * @param {Object} options
 * @constructor
 */
function RecognizeStream(options) {
  Duplex.call(this, options);
  this.options = options;
  this.listening = false;
  this.initialized = false;
}
util.inherits(RecognizeStream, Duplex);

RecognizeStream.prototype.initialize = function() {
  const options = this.options;

  if (options.token && !options['watson-token']) {
    options['watson-token'] = options.token;
  }
  if (options.content_type && !options['content-type']) {
    options['content-type'] = options.content_type;
  }
  if (options['X-WDC-PL-OPT-OUT'] && !options['X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out']) {
    options['X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out'] = options['X-WDC-PL-OPT-OUT'];
  }

  const queryParams = extend({ model: 'en-US_BroadbandModel' }, pick(options, QUERY_PARAMS_ALLOWED));
  const queryString = Object.keys(queryParams)
    .map(function(key) {
      return key + '=' + (key === 'watson-token' ? queryParams[key] : encodeURIComponent(queryParams[key])); // our server chokes if the token is correctly url-encoded
    })
    .join('&');

  const url = (options.url || 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api').replace(/^http/, 'ws') + '/v1/recognize?' + queryString;

  const openingMessage = extend(
    {
      action: 'start',
      'content-type': 'audio/wav',
      continuous: true,
      interim_results: true,
      word_confidence: true,
      timestamps: true,
      max_alternatives: 3,
      inactivity_timeout: 600
    },
    pick(options, OPENING_MESSAGE_PARAMS_ALLOWED)
  );
```

This code is from IBM Developers and for my project I'm using and works perfectly.

You can see in the code line [#53](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/speech-to-text/recognize_stream.js#L53), set the listening to `true`, otherwise it will eventually timeout and close automatically with `inactivity_timeout` applies when you're sending audio with no speech in it, not when you aren't sending any data at all.

Have another example, see [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk) example from IBM Watson - Watson Developer Cloud using Javascript for Speech to Text.